# Java commons-csv doesn't parse header

Tags: java, csv, apache-commons-csv

I have an EXCEL CSV file with this content:

```
access_id;logicalgate
123456789;TEST
```

As you can see header has strings and are not quoted.

With this code:

```
fileReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"));
csvParser = new CSVParser(fileReader, CSVFormat.EXCEL.withNullString("").withFirstRecordAsHeader().withIgnoreHeaderCase().withQuoteMode(QuoteMode.MINIMAL).withIgnoreEmptyLines().withTrim());
```

The output of this command:

```
csvParser.getHeaderMap()
```

Is a **single** element map!

```
(java.util.TreeMap<K,V>) {﻿access_id;logicalgate=0}
```

With a concatendated key "﻿*access_id;logicalgate*"

Why the parser is missing the header separation?

Comment: I can't see anywhere where you specify that a semicolon is the delimiter. How's it supposed to know? Needs `.withDelimiter(';')`, surely? I imagine the rows themselves are also broken.

Comment: the [CSVFormat.EXCEL](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/apidocs/org/apache/commons/csv/CSVFormat.html#EXCEL) specifies the delimiter, just the wrong one (`,`) in this case.

Comment: Incredible... thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CsvFormat.EXCEL` is defined with delimiter `,` not `;`, you should add `.withDelimiter(';')`.

> `public static final CSVFormat EXCEL`
>
> Excel file format (using a comma as the value delimiter). Note that
> the actual value delimiter used by Excel is locale dependent, it might
> be necessary to customize this format to accommodate to your regional
> settings.
>
> For example for parsing or generating a CSV file on a French system
> the following format will be used:
>
> `CSVFormat fmt = CSVFormat.EXCEL.withDelimiter(';');`
>
> The CSVFormat.Builder settings are:
>
> ```
> setDelimiter(',')
> setQuote('"')
> setRecordSeparator("\r\n")
> setIgnoreEmptyLines(false)
> setAllowMissingColumnNames(true)
> setAllowDuplicateHeaderNames(true)
> ```
>
> -- https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/apidocs/org/apache/commons/csv/CSVFormat.html#EXCEL

Comment: I'm wondering why naming "EXCEL" when the format is different...

Comment: I think excel format refers to the permitting missing column names and not ignoring empty lines, but not to the separator.

Comment: Yes, the separator is a detail ;-)